# Inserting into a specific schema with Cassandra stress tool

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-stress

`Cassandra-stress` tool inserts data into the default keyspace `Keyspace1`. How can I insert into a specific keyspace?

Thanks
Smitha

Answer (score 4):

The latest stress tool for cassandra 2.1 allows you to create your own schema and even comes with 3 example schemas, one of which called `cqlstress-example.yaml`. They can be found in `C*-dir/tools/`.

You can issue a stress command as follows:

```
./bin/cassandra-stress user profile=./cqlstress-example.yaml ops\(insert=1\)
```

[This blog](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improved-cassandra-2-1-stress-tool-benchmark-any-schema) covers the custom stressing with the tool.

Answer (score 2):

Latest cassandra-stress tool provides the option of -schema that you can use to specify your own keyspace/schema. E.g.

cassandra-stress read n=200000 -schema keyspace="myOwnKeyspace"